# How to display results as a table within SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, messagebox

Is it possible to put whole table with results in a `MessageBox.Show()`?

I'm passing results from SQL to an SSIS variable using FullResultSet.

I can print each of the results within a message box separately (without table).

But clicking OK many times to verify my results it's quite annoying. Would it be possible to print my results at once?

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably approcah this in a different way.

Try adding a [Data viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx) to your control flow. combined with [breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141754.aspx) this is a very efficient way of being able to peek into the data within your package.

Comment: Thanks for that! It is so simple but it works! I don't need to pass the FullResultSet and use it to display the table with the results anymore.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Right now I have some layers:
0:Master - where I can execute specific solutions
1: Solution - where I can execute tasks - from this level the results might be printed using Data Viewer. But I can't display the same table from Master Level - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was wondering the same thing and found the solution to this, so I thought I'd share.

Under the `Control Flow` tab, create an `Execute SQL Task` from the `SSIS ToolBox`.

Open the `Execute SQL Task` and enter the params for `ConnectionType`, `Connection` and `SQLStatement`.

Then click on the button: `Build Query...` and click the play button at the top.

You now are viewing the results right in SSIS. =)